# Visual Studio 2019: how to fix command line error D8027: cannot execute 'Path\To\c1xx.dll'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm having the following error everytime I compile even a basic hello world program in VS 19 community edition after reinstalling it

```
command line error D8027: cannot execute 'Path\To\c1xx.dll'
```

how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using Windows 7 by any chance?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cl-command-line-error-d8027-cannot-execute-pathtoc/1106548

Comment: @user7860670 Yes I am using windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you should refer to the link provided by Alan Birtles: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cl-command-line-error-d8027-cannot-execute-pathtoc/1106548

The problem is due to cl.exe loading the c1.dll library with the [LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-setdefaultdlldirectories) which is unsupported on a plain Windows 7.

The solution is to install [KB2758857](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35936) which adds support for this flag.

Comment: @Noctis Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us.
Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.